# Minimum requirements for enabling reset password functionality in Azure

Tags: active-directory, azure

I recently got back from Holidays to discover that I am no longer able to login to my work (Azure/Microsoft?) account. This account was added through 'Active Directory' (free) as a guest.

When I attempt to reset the account password I get a message stating that Admin has not enabled/configured reset functionality.

My fellow co-worker is the 'Global Administrator' for our Azure account/services but the 'Reset Password' option is disabled for all users within Azure dashboard, including themselves, and the option to enable external 'Password Reset' is not available in 'Active Directory' without upgrading to 'Premium'.

We would like to know the simplest way to re-enable my account. Is there are way to reset an account password for free or do we have to enable some paid Azure services to do so?

Additional info:

I've tried deleting the 'Quest' account in 'Active Directory' but if you attempt to re-add a guest account with the same email address it prompts for a password (the first time I did this it prompted to set a password). I still don't know the password so I still cannot log-in.

Comment: Why is this being down voted? Is this question not suitable for 'ServerFault'? Should I be asking elsewhere?

Comment: Have another administrator reset your password.

Comment: There is only one 'Global Administrator' and the function is disabled! There is no other administrator.

Comment: If you locked yourself out of your account, contact microsoft.

Comment: @Appleoddity Which part of microsoft? Without paid support Azure sends you to twitter which I tried but got no response (so here I am).

Answer (score 0):

If by *guest* you mean you have an account in this tenant Azure AD, then just ask another Global Administrator in the tenant, they will be able to reset your password within the portal. If by *guest* you mean you are a Global Admin, but you're using your own Microsoft Account (not corporate), then all you have to do is to reset the password for the Microsoft Account and that has nothing to do with the Azure Tenant.

Self-Service Password Reset is a paid feature, and besides enabling it, each user still has to configure a second and a third authentication mechanism such as e-mail and mobile phones to be able to do it.

if you're locked out of the tenant and there's no one else that could perform the reset, you need to contact Microsoft. I'm not aware of any means of contacting support outside of the Azure Portal besides Twitter.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/support/options/

There will definitely exist an account with self-service password reset configured in the tenant and that is the Service Administrator. The account used to setup the tenant for the first time.